# SQL Pivot Table help or possible other solution

Tags: sql, subquery, pivot, ssms, pivot-table

I am trying to write a query to figure out the versions that are installed on machines. the database is setup like this.

```
machine name | Program Name | Version
Machine1         Program1      5.0
Machine1         Program2      4.6
Machine1         Program3      15.2
Machine2         Program1      4.9
Machine2         Program2      4.6
Machine2         Program3      15.1
```

I would like them to be output like this

```
Machinename | Program1 Version | Program2 Version | Program3 Version
Machine1            5.0                4.6                15.2
Machine2            4.9                4.6                15.1
```

I have heard about pivot tables and sub queries but i cannot for the life of me figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.  I keep seeing responses that add up the values or min max the values.  I am just trying to re-order the list.

Comment: Post some of the code you have tried, you could be close.  It helps everyone help you by seeing your working.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
http://rextester.com/OHASM46132

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
       [machine],
    Program,
        Version
    FROM tbl
) as s
PIVOT
(
   max(version)
    FOR [Program] IN (program1, program2, program3)
)AS pvt
```

A couple of things: using a pivot, the value has to be an aggregate (Count, max, sum, etc). You have to manually enter the program names in the `FOR [Program]` block. If the programs are variable, you can use dynamic SQL to create the query (there are plenty of SE questions related to dynamic pivot, IIRC)

Answer (score 1):

A quick dynamic conditional aggregation may help

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)=''
Select @SQL = @SQL+char(13)+','+QUOTENAME(ProgramName+' Version')+'=max(case when ProgramName='''+ProgramName+''' then Version else null end)'
 From (Select Distinct ProgramName from YourTable) A
 Order By ProgramName

Select @SQL='Select MachineName'+@SQL+' From YourTable Group By MachineName'
Exec(@SQL)
```

The SQL Generated is a follows

```
Select MachineName
    ,[Program1 Version]=max(case when ProgramName='Program1' then Version else null end)
    ,[Program2 Version]=max(case when ProgramName='Program2' then Version else null end)
    ,[Program3 Version]=max(case when ProgramName='Program3' then Version else null end) 
From YourTable 
Group By MachineName
```

Comment: This is going to break if `ProgramName` has single quotes in it.